# creating a mini profile with php, having issues with upload photo and assigning the to each member

Tags: php, database, image, image-uploading

I am trying to create a mini profile where it displays, peoples name, position in the company, phone number, Email, Bio and a slot for a profile photo. My issue is I already know how to upload images and crop them, but I have searched feverishly to no avail to try and figure out a way  in which I could upload a profile to link each user id, eg. like how your facebook profile pic automatically links to your user id, any suggestions? and would i have to use the same database(Mysql) table in order to do so? or could I call a specific id? and what if i want to change the pic for the same profile later, would i have to re-create the profile? or is there a way i can tag each profile and access each profile on click?

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include('connect.php');

if(is_dir('hftpnyc/dir_thumbs') == false ){
mkdir('hftpnyc/dir_thumbs', 0744);} 

$dir_pos = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Dir_pos']);
$dir_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Dir_name']);
$occu=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Occu']);
$bio = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Bio']);
$pic = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dir_pic']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$Numb = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['num']);
$cr8 = isset($_POST['cr8']);
$errmsg = array();
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `directors`");
$get = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

if($cr8){

if( $dir_pos && $dir_name && $occu){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `hftpnyc`.`directors` (`Positition`,`name`,`Email`,`Num`,`occupation`,`Bio`,`dir_pic`) VALUES     ('{$dir_pos}','{$dir_name}','{$email}','{$Numb}','{$occu}','{$bio}','{$encoded}')");

header('location:Directors.php');
}
}

?>

<form name="Director_create" method="post" id="form" actio="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"/>
Director position: <br/> 
<input class="text_user"  id="nick" type="text" name="Dir_pos" MAXLENGTH="55"   />  

Director name:

<input  name="Dir_name" type="text" id="messagebox" />



Contact Number:
<p style="color:#F00; font-size:9px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;">*optional*</p>

   <input  name="num" type="text" id="messagebox" />

Email Address:

<input  name="email" type="text" id="messagebox" />

Occupation:

<input  name="Occu" cols="20" class="text" id="messagebox" />


Biography:

<textarea ty  name="Bio" class="text" id="messagebox"  ></textarea>
<br/> 
<input id="send" name="cr8" type="submit" value="CREATE" /> 

</form>
```

I have the code to display what should be echo for each profile below.

```
<?php
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `directors` ORDER BY  `Director_id` DESC;") ;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{

$email1 = $row['Email'];
$enc = $row['dir_pic'];
$name= $row['name'];
$posit = $row['Positition'];
$num1 = $row['Num'];
$occupation = $row['occupation'];
$Biography = $row['Bio']; 

?>

<div id="direc" style="height:10px; width:100%;margin-bottom:8px;">

<h3 class="heading" style="margin:0px auto;color:#666; border-bottom: #A3308E solid 1px;font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:15px"> <?php echo $posit; ?>: <?php    echo $name; ?></h3> </div>

<div class="photocase" style="width:100px; height:100px; float:left;border-width: 1px;border:solid black 1px;margin: 5px; ">
<img src="<?php echo /*This is where i want each photo*/; ?>" width="100px" />
</div>
<div  style="width:360px;height:30px; display:block;float:left;margin-top:5px; line-height:3px;">

<p>OCCUPATION: <?php echo $occupation; ?></p>
</div>    

<div  style="width:360px;height:30px; display:block;float:left;margin-top:5px; line-height:3px;">

<p align="justify">Email: <?php echo $email1; ?></p>
</div>  

<div  style="width:360px;height:30px; display:block;float:left;margin-top:5px; line-height:3px;">

<p align="justify">Contact #: <?php echo $num1; ?></p>
</div>


<div style="float:left;display:block;width:98%;height:16px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:1.5%; ">
<p>Bio:<?php echo $Biography;?></p>
</div>
</div>
<?php


}

?>
```

Comment: what are you storing in dir_pic column? You could store the location of the user's pic there. Then you can retrieve it and use it as the src of the img tag...

Comment: @boug that's the idea, however the problem i am having it how do i assign each profile a there specific pic, using the individual id, and i want to be able to change that pic at anytime.

Answer (score 0):

create a table like users table which will have all the typical info of a user. In the same table have a column called like profile_pic which may contain just the image name or entire path to the image. In the case, you are storing just the image name make sure you upload all the images to a particular folder. The problem here is that that folder gets very big as more users are added to the database. One way of solving it is create a new folder automatically for a new month. Later when you want to access the image of a profile, you can know the folder from the timestamp of users creation time.

Coming to your second question, of how to access a profile, its very simple. 
The very basic of every table creation is to have a key/column called id, which would the primary key for the table. It would ofcourse be unique. So each user is referenced with this key called id. You can put an anutoincrement attribute to this column. So everytime you add a new user his id number is automatically created by mysql.

Now suppose a user's id is 43. For viewing a particular profile, you would have a page called profile.php

if the request is like

```
profile.phP?id=43
```

then from $_GET['id'], you can query in the database like

```
'select * from users where id = "'.$_GET['id'].'" ';
```

Comment: I have all of that already, how can after creating the profile, access any single individual profile, given that they will be dynamically loaded. eg. Say I have 20 profiles within the database, however and i dynamically load all of them, how can i go about selecting only one on click. to edit it? like how u would change your profile pic or your relationship stat etc. even though all of that is dynamically loaded